# Not able to sort my custom Adapter : Android

Tags: android, sorting, collections

I have a activity in which i have setAdapter to a gridview .
Data are getting loaded perfectly fine .
I have a menu which have two options 1. Sort by Price and 2. Sort by Class

This is the function i have in my custom Adapter

```
public void sortlistbyPrice(){
    Collections.sort(flightObjLists, new Comparator<FlightEntity>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(FlightEntity lhs, FlightEntity rhs) {
            return lhs.getPrice()==rhs.getPrice()?1:0;
        }
    });
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

I am invoking this function from the Activity whenever i want to display items in a sorted way .

But unfortunately it is not happening , can anyone help me out over here ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you test it for us?

```
public void sortlistbyPrice(){
    Collections.sort(flightObjLists, new Comparator<FlightEntity>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(FlightEntity lhs, FlightEntity rhs) {
            return lhs.getPrice() < rhs.getPrice() ? -1 : lhs.getPrice() == rhs.getPrice()? 1 : 0;
        }
    });
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: it worked , can you tell me what was i doing wrong?  What would be the logic if getPrice returns me a boolean , what would be the logic in that case since i cannot use < operation on booleans

Comment: Sure, @Kapil Bhandari :). There are three cases that you gotta check, whether the price is lower, equals or higher. In your code, you only verified whether it was equals or not.

Comment: What would be the logic if getPrice returns me a boolean , what would be the logic in that case since i cannot use < operation on booleans

Comment: In that case, you would not be able to sort by higher or lower, because boolean (primitive) only has two possible comparison results: equals or different.